# How to fix android error "method openFileInput in class Context cannot be applied to given types;2

Tags: java, android

Within my `MainActivity.java` I am trying to open a file according to the code [given here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14768191/how-do-i-read-the-file-content-from-the-internal-storage-android-app). But when running the code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "YOUR TEXT HERE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                // Perform action on click

                FileInputStream fis = getBaseContext().openFileInput("hello.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(isr);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line;
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line);
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

I get the following error:

```
Error:(27, 55) error: method openFileInput in class Context cannot be applied to given types;
required: String
found: String,int
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

I am not even able to understand what the error means. What 'argument list' is the message referring to?

Comment: pass only file name instead of filename and mode in `FileInputStream`. Before using someones code from stackoverflow try to read comments as well

Comment: That seems to work. So I guess the example code is wrong, for some reasons.

Comment: Don't use `getBaseContext()` unless you know what you're doing with it, and have an explicit reason to. Just call `openFileInput()` directly on the `Activity`, which is a `Context`.

Comment: Even better. I have no idea what `getBaseContext()` does ...

Comment: And yeah, that example is wrong. `openFileInput()` only takes the `String` argument.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @MuhammadKashifArif:

Instead of this

```
FileInputStream fis = getBaseContext().openFileInput("hello.txt",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

use this

```
FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("hello.txt", MODE_PRIVATE);
```

It doesn't matter.

Context is context, and getBase context is still the same context as everything else, calling getBaseContext doesn't change the type of context compared to using `this` in an activity. There is no difference between accessing `MODE_PRIVATE` statically and using `import static`

I am not sure when exactly this changed (and I am not going to look through every version of android to check either), but it is `openFileOutput` that takes two arguments, a String an an Integer.

`openFileInput` now only takes one argument. So:

```
FileInputStream fis = /*Some context here if you are outside an activity.*/openFileInput("hello.txt");
```

And to load:

```
FileOutputStream fos = /*some context if outside activity.*/openFileOutput("hello.txt", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

And I would once again like to clear up the fact that it doesn't make a difference whether or not you call getBaseContext, getApplicationContext, or call `this`/`SomeActivity.this` inside an activity. The context class itself doesn't change, the fields are the same. And writing `MODE_PRIVATE` without `Context.` in front of it is called a static import. The only difference between `Context.MODE_PRIVATE` and the static import `MODE_PRIVATE` is only you don't have to type those characters. The method **doesn't exist no matter how you call it**

---

As for the compile error, it basically says you are supplying more arguments than the method requires. You should also see a red warning over the call to the method as well, but what you see is the compile error as you tried to compile the build while there is a call to an unknown method.

Answer (score 0):

As @LunarWatcher said the openFileInput takes 1 parameter.So,

Instead of this

```
FileInputStream fis = getBaseContext().openFileInput("hello.txt",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

use this

```
FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("hello.txt");
```

Comment: **openFileInput doesn't take two parameters**. It **used to** but doesn't any more. It is openFIleOutput that takes two parameters

Comment: LunarWatcher yes you are right. i have not focus on it.