# Where to put a file in android so it can be opened?

Tags: android

I want to open a file in android using the following code:

```
 FileInputStream fis = openFileInput("examplelist.txt");
 InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
 BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(isr);
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 String line;
 while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
     sb.append(line);
 }
```

but where to put the file `examplelist.txt`? I found some contradicting sources, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14768191/how-do-i-read-the-file-content-from-the-internal-storage-android-app) and [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/47924/where-android-apps-store-data)? How to do it correctly?

**Update:**

I want to be able to replace this file at anytime after the app has been installed. So this file is NOT part of the source code or anything. It contains dynamical data...

I would have used a simple 'File Selector', so the user can navigate to the file anywhere on the android phone, but this looks terribly complicated and cumbersome. So, for now, I just want to open a file I can put somewhere on the phone in the *most possible simple manner...*

Comment: Most apps I use seem to create a folder in the root of the internal card, then use that to contain any files they need.

Comment: And where is that root?

Comment: On my phone, it's in `storage/emulated/0`, but I think the API exposes a method that returns the internal and external card paths.

Comment: Another option if you want a "File Picker" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8945531/pick-any-kind-file-via-an-intent-on-android

Comment: @cricket_007: That's an answer I refer to. I actually have no file `data/data/<myapp>` ...

Comment: You are asking about just reading from the Android SD card(s), which are addressed in enough detail in the documentation. Whether you don't have a specific directory shouldn't matter, I don't think https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Comment: @cricket_007: The you can surely tell me at which my code is wrong!

Comment: I don't understand why you think it is wrong. `/data` is on the root partition, not a folder that you'd be able to see immediately on the device.

Comment: I put the file in the following directory: `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.alexander.learn/files/examplelist.txt`. This is, to the best of my knowledge, as explained in the posts I have linked, the location I try to access in the code I have presented. However, an exception is thrown. The files does not to be present at the location tryied to be opened in the code given above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133032/discussion-between-alex-and-cricket-007).

Comment: You could comment below on CommonsWare comprehensive answer for any clarification

Comment: @cricket_007: I don't understand the answer provided by CommonsWare. Also, it seems incomplete, describing just general suggestions (like 'google it'), which is no help at all!

Comment: That's why you have the ability to comment on it

Comment: @cricket_007: Yes you are right. I have added a comment

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to access a file, you should place it in `/app/src/main/assets/examplelist.txt`. You can access this directory in the Project explorer in Android Studio.

To open the file from java code, you can create an `InputStream` object by calling `getAssets().open("examplelist.txt")`

Comment: Damn, I should have cleared my question more precise. Please see updated question.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to solve this problem is the following:

1. You put the file in the kind-of-root folder, which might have the following path: `/storage/emulated/0` (this is the location you can see when you connect the device e.g. to Linux and open it in the file explorer).
2. You can open the content of the file using the following code:

   ```
   String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
   Log.d("Files", "Path: " + path);

   String joinedPath = new File(path, "examplelist.txt").toString();
   try {
       FileInputStream fis =new FileInputStream(new File(joinedPath));
       InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
       BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(isr);
       StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
       String line;
       while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
           sb.append(line);
       }
       Log.d("Text", sb.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
       Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "File does not exist", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
   ```
3. VERY IMPORTANT, and which I forget EVERY single time: You have to set permission to the app to access the storage. You have to put the `permission` tag in the `AndroidMainfest.xml`

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
   <application
       android:allowBackup="true"
       android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
       ...
   ```

Answer (score -1):

> but where to put the file examplelist.txt?

Your app would create the file itself. `openFileInput()` is part of [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html), to which ordinary users have no access.

> I would have used a simple 'File Selector', so the user can navigate to the file anywhere on the android phone, but this looks terribly complicated and cumbersome.

Step #1: Call `startActivityForResult()` with an `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` or `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` `Intent` (the former is for Android 4.4+)

Step #2: In `onActivityResult()`, if you get `RESULT_OK` as a result, get the `Uri` to the user's chosen content via `getData()` on the `Intent` passed into `onActivityResult()`

Step #3: Call `openInputStream()` on a `ContentResolver` to get an `InputStream` to use for reading the content

It's about 10-15 lines of code over what you have in your question, plus the code that your question needs but does not show (e.g., background thread for I/O).

Or, use [a file chooser library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/35?sort=created).

> I just want to open a file I can put somewhere on the phone in the most possible simple manner...

Use [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html), such as `getExternalFilesDir()`.

Comment: I dont understand this answer. Why should I use `Intents` and `RESULT_OK` items, when I just want to open a file? Example in python: `open("filename")`. I just want to do the same in android.

Comment: @Alex: "Why should I use Intents and RESULT_OK items, when I just want to open a file?" -- you wrote in your question "I would have used a simple 'File Selector'...". Those three steps are how you implement a simple file selector. If you did not want to implement a simple file selector, you should not have included that in your question.

Comment: Maybe you are right in order to provide vague steps to use a file selector. But you did not provide example code; I also do not agree that this is 'simple'. Simple is something like this: `String filename = FileSelector();`, or something like this. But the way you have described does not look simple to me. But complex and way too complicated. Maybe there is no simple solution in android.