# Why is the list of files empty if reading the content from getExternalStorageDirectory?

Tags: android

Following an answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14768191/how-do-i-read-the-file-content-from-the-internal-storage-android-app) I have run the following code:

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
Log.d("Files", "Path: " + path);
File f = new File(path);
File file[] = f.listFiles();
Log.d("Files", "Size: " + file.length);
```

which results in an NullPointerException, as the array `file` seems to be empty. However, the location `/storage/emulated/0` to which the variable `path` refers to, is NOT empty.

What is going on? Why is the list of files empty, althugh there are files in that directory?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/android-permission-doesnt-work-even-if-i-have-declared-it

Comment: Yes, thats it! And I have this problem EACH time when creating an android app.