# Text file not found android studio?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to build a simple app for Android can't figure out why my app keeps crashing I have traced it down to this line of code

```
<code>WG.setRandomWord(words.get(rand.nextInt(words.size())));</code>
```

I have check my logcat and it showing that my word file is not even being detected `com.sagproductions.gamertaggenerator W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: words.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)` but I have my file word file in the document structure.

for more context here is my code:

JAVA wordGenerator

```
package com.sagproductions.gamertaggenerator;


public class WordGenerator {
    private String mRandomWord;
    private int mRandomNum;

    public WordGenerator(String randomWord, int randomNum){
        mRandomNum=randomNum;
        mRandomWord=randomWord;
    }

    public int getRandomNum(){
        return mRandomNum;
    }

    public void setRandomNum(int randomNum){
        mRandomNum=randomNum;
    }

    public String getRandomWord(){
        return mRandomWord;
    }

    public void setRandomWord(String randomWord){
        mRandomWord=randomWord;
    }
}
```

Java MainActivity

```
package com.sagproductions.gamertaggenerator;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.lang.String;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    WordGenerator WG;
    private Button mSingleWordGenerator;
    private Button mTwoWordGenerator;
    private Button mThreeWordGenerator;
    private EditText editText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mSingleWordGenerator = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
        mSingleWordGenerator.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                generateWord();
                editText=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
               editText.setText(WG.getRandomWord(),TextView.BufferType.EDITABLE);
            }
        });

        mTwoWordGenerator = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        mTwoWordGenerator.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        mThreeWordGenerator = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
        mThreeWordGenerator.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
    }

    public void generateWord(){
        final File file = new File("words.txt");
        ArrayList<String> words= new ArrayList<String>();
        Random rand=new Random();

        try(final Scanner scanner=new Scanner(file)){
            while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                words.add(line);
            }
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        WG.setRandomWord(words.get(rand.nextInt(words.size())));
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14768191/how-do-i-read-the-file-content-from-the-internal-storage-android-app

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18302603/where-do-i-place-the-assets-folder-in-android-studio and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9544737/read-file-from-assets

Answer (score 0):

The `WG` field is never initialized, so it's `null`. So you're probably getting a NullPointerException when you call that method. You should initialize it somewhere, perhaps when you declare it (so `WordGenerator WG;` would be replaced by something like `WordGenerator WG = new WordGenerator(INITIAL_RANDOM_WORD, INITIAL_RANDOM_VALUE);`, where INITIAL_RANDOM_WORD and INITIAL_RANDOM_VALUE are some values you define elsewhere).

**Edit:** It seems that that line is causing the problem because `words.size()` is `0`, which is because of the FileNotFoundException. The correct way to read that file will depend on where you're putting it. See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12421814/how-can-i-read-a-text-file-in-android) (and the pages they link to) for different ways to correctly read text files in Android.

Comment: I tried that to no avail. I checked the android monitor again and it is saying that the exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException at Random.nextInt at generateword