# Android File not Found Exception Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, readfile, file-not-found

So I have a really simple project:

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    val bundle = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeCustomAnimation(applicationContext, android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out).toBundle()
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val myObj = File("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\k.txt")
    val myReader = Scanner(myObj)
}
```

and I have a "k.txt" file on my desktop.
Whenever `val myReader = Scanner(myObj)` comes it throws a:

> ```
>  Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\user\Desktop\k.txt (No such file or directory)
> ```

why is that?

thanks for any help!

Comment: Add your file in res/raw/k.txt  and then access inside the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not access storage computer

You coppy file in internal storage or external storage ( Phone Storage or SD card Storage)

Next step : [Read file internal storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14768191/how-do-i-read-the-file-content-from-the-internal-storage-android-app#:%7E:text=To%20read%20a%20file%20from,the%20file%20with%20read().)

Hope it`s fully

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly open or create file object from you local machine.